# How can I copy mp4 file from raw folder to shared storage? (Android12 Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Thank you for read this question.
I'm new to android development.

Now,I'm trying to copy some ".mp4" files in raw folder to shared storage(sdcar/Movies).

To make it,I wrote the code below.

As a result,The file name was copied, but When I try to play the video, it says "Can't play video". How can I copy .mp4 files to shared storage(sdcard/Movies)?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    
  copyVideo()

}

private fun copyVideo(){
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "video_name")
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }

    val collection = MediaStore.Video.Media
        .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    val item = contentResolver.insert(collection, values)!!

    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(item, "w", null).use {
        // write something to OutputStream
        FileOutputStream(it!!.fileDescriptor).use { outputStream ->
            val videoInputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.video_name)
            
            while (true) {
                val data = videoInputStream.read()
                if (data == -1) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(data)
            }
            videoInputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()
        }
    }


    values.clear()
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    contentResolver.update(item, values, null, null)
}
```

Comment: How many bytes in original file and copied file?

Comment: You are nowhere telling the mediastore the DCIM folder. And on Android 11+ video files are not accepted for DCIM folder. In which folder did they land?

Comment: You are talking about shared storage instead of media store.

Comment: @blackapps  Thank you for your comments! Now I checked files,original file is 3.5MB and copied file is 3.4MB. Copied file had been copied sdcard/Movies folder.

Comment: How many bytes do they differ? Exactly!

Comment: Test with contentResolver.openOutputStream(item).

Comment: I checked both size. There size(original and copied) are same. Copied file isn't corruped? But, When I try to play the video, it says "Can't play video".

Comment: @blackapps Sorry,I can't fully understand your advice. Where should I write "contentResolver.openOutputStream(item)" ?

Comment: Use it for videoInputStream was the hint.

Comment: @blackapps After trying a lot of things, I was able to copy it successfully. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Well why dont you tell how you did it and why not posted the better code?

Comment: @blackapps It worked fine before the code was modified.I don't know the exact cause, but it worked fine when I deleted all the extra copied videos in the emulator.However, after saving the video, when I took a video with the emulator's camera and displayed the video list with the photo app, I could not open the video again.

Comment: I haven't found better code, so I'm thinking of a different approach than what I'm trying to do now.